# How can be home controller define as root also when action have params? asp.mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

By default if url is 'mydomain' it go to controller home; action = index.

But when index action has params the url have to be:

```
mydomain/home/index?name=John
```

want to get:

```
mydomain?name=John
```

What should be define for create such url?

Thanks,

Yosef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want `mydomain/home/index?name=John` and `mydomain?name=John` as your urls in your site?

If you corrected your routing engine, your routes could be, `mydomain/home/index/john` and `mydomain/john`, which to me would be more correct.

Is that what you're going for?

If so, assuming you have a Index action, accepting a string parameter of name in your home controller, you could modify your global.asax, and change the default route, and add a route below the standard default route like this:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
       "Default", // Route name
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name= UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
     );

     routes.MapRoute(
       "NameOnly", // Route name
       "{name}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
     );
```

Be sure you put the name only route at the bottom, as a string based parameter will match everything, so you need to match the more explicit ones first.

Comment: my controller is for ajax calls for website - dont need friendly url

Answer (score 2):

The correct url is the following:

```
http://mydomain.com/?name=John
```

Given default route setup this will invoke the `Index` action on `Home` controller and pass the `name` parameter.

As far as your request about the `mydomain?name=John` url is considered, well, this doesn't look quite a well formed url.